# Ads: Failed to load ad: 3 error on old package name

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I added interstitial & banner ads to my app which is on the google play store.
But I got W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3 error.

I tried test ads and that is doesn't work too. I created a demo app with the same code and the test ad is shown.  My AdMob has not no violations.

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just be patient. Google doesn't always provide ads for you and your users, even test ads. I got the same error 3 when i published my app and there was no ad. But later on,  it started to appear and gradually increased.